# Drupal View query for select fields produces different results that CiviCRM

Tags: drupal-views, multiple-choice

I have a civicrm custom field for languages spoken like

```
English
French
German
...
```

You can have multiple selections.

SO a contact might select

```
English
French
```

from the listing.

If I do a search for "French" in CiviCRM it returns contacts correctly.

If I do it in Drupal via an exposed filter in a View, it returns no contacts.

If I do a Drupal search for English, it returns the contact.

It seems like it only returns a result if the item being searched is the first in the list - in this case English.

Ive tried allow multiple selection in the View filter and so on, with no result.

I want it to produce the correct results.

Any ideas? Thanks as always.

Comment: What is your civi version?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't upgraded Civi to 5.28.4 than apply below patch

https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/617.patch

https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/618.patch